# How can I circle a UIView on the spot as an animation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I'm having difficulty understanding how I would go about circling a `UIView` on the spot as an animation and put it in Swift code?

I have a single `UIView` (named `myView` that always must remain upright (the `UIView` doesn't rotate). But then, I want to start a continuous animation that pushes the `UIView` out to the side and moves it around in a perfect circle on the spot.

I've made a mock up of the `UIView` below showing how the `UIView` stays upright but circles around its original position.

The animation is almost like when circling the mouse cursor in the one spot. The mouse cursor remains the same, but circles in the one spot.

And as the animation runs continuously, I want to be able to stop it at anytime with a call.

I've considered using a concise `UIView.animateWithDuration` with a `myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`, however I don't understand how to make the translation circle on the spot.

Any help with a solution appreciated.

[image]

Very similar to this animation, the way it moves in a circle:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say "on the spot"? What spot?

Comment: By "on the spot" I guess I mean in close vacinity to the original position, the centre point wouldn't drift too far away from its original position. Something very similar to this animation: https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/309027/screenshots/2281979/weather-parallax-large.gif and http://blog.storehouse.co/content/images/2015/10/settings.gif